# Detect button onlongclicklistener leave (up) event?

Tags: android, buttonclick

I want to detect the button leave or up event. I have a button and i press it, now i want to show message when i leave the button.

```
inner_img.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
     {  
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            //Button press event
            return false;
        }       

    });
```

Now i need the button  leave(up) event

Comment: Can you use setOnTouchListener - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener) , on the button and filter the MotionEvent parameter for ACTION_UP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to implement the `OnTouchListener`
Something like:

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //do stuff here!
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Use the action down and up/cancel to implement your custom longclick duration

Comment: Thank you brother for being so nice